# A riddle I made up for my kids a while ago

Tags: riddle

Explain "Two has three, and four has three, but three has only one".

Comment: Were they able to solve the riddle?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe you are talking about

> Homophones
>
>  "Two" also has "to" and "too", "Four" also has "for" and "fore", but "three" has no homophones.

Comment: English isnt my first lenguaje, But Three sound like Tree, not sure if that is the same.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In US English, "three" is pronounced [/θɹi/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/three) (with a voiceless dental fricative at the beginning), but in some dialects, there is what is known as [th-stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-stopping), the phenomenon you describe.

Comment: I always though there was a slight difference between four and for. Just checked in wiktionary, turns out the en-US pronunciation of both is the same!

Comment: In the NATO phonetic alphabet, three is pronounced "tree" and four is pronounced "fo-wer", so if you find this riddle confusing then maybe you're meant to be a pilot!

Comment: @njzk2 There's probably a difference in some regional accent somewhere, but for most dialects of English they're homophones.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I find a lot of things confusing. Maybe...

Comment: is it Homophones, or Heterograph.

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about

> heterographs
>  2 has two, too, and to.
> 4 has four, for, and fore.
> and three has only three.
>  this also means that 1 would have two (one, and won);and 8 would also have two (eight, and ate).

p.s.

> if you speak German then nine has two as well(nine and nien)

p.s.s. I really like this puzzle. I have tried it out on my siblings. we had lots of fun.